# how to detect the category from search text in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I want to know how to detect the category from text search of the users, for example in amazon.com when I enter "asus" in the search box amazon detect that "asus" is of "electronics > computer" category and give me the relevant filter for that category.

I want to have the same experience in my website
Can anyone help me or explain how is amazon doing it?
I am using elasticsearch to power search on my platform

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually done by tagging your Elasticsearch documents with this sort of metadata during ingestion. how to do that depends entirely on your ingestion process

Comment: Can you please explain more on this

Comment: when you add a document, you add something like `"category": "computers"` to let you filter things down